# iptableで間違えて拒否したipを戻す方法

Tags: iptables

`iptables -I INPUT -s 間違えたip -j DROP`

これを戻すにはどうしたらよいのでしょうか。
またそれの確認方法を教えて下さい。

Answer (score 2):

（後半部分の入力をいとわなければ）単純に`-D`オプションに変えるとエントリ削除されます。

```
iptables -D INPUT -s 間違えたip -j DROP
```

または`--line-numbers`オプション付きでリスト表示(`-L`)させ、行番号指定で該当エントリを削除できます。

```
iptables -L INPUT --line-numbers
iptables -D INPUT <番号>
```

[本家回答](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10197405/iptables-remove-specific-rules)も参考になります。

Answer (score 1):

たまたま発見したのですが、以下のサイトが参考になりそうです。

http://tejunsho.com/os/20110331000108.html